# Copy power query from a worbook, execute it and load its result into another workbook (with vba)

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I got a group of parameterized queries in a workbook and i want to execute these queries into others workbooks.

One of these queries is for exemple Fxquery(Tab as Table) and Tab would be a table on the first sheet of each workbook.

Actually a can get all the queries from the origine file and go throught all the workbook i want to apply the modifications. But i do not know how to execute the queries withtout just copying the m code.

Thank you.
(Excuse me if there is any fault i'm not that good in english)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can not execute M code in a file without having the M code in there.  You could write a VBA that opens each file and dynamically creates the M code you want in each file (tag a question to VBA ).  Or perhaps, set up each file in advance to have a query that reads in shared M code that can be executed:

```
//Load shared M code from text file
let  Source = Text.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\PowerQueryQueries\DynamicQuery.txt")),
EvaluatedExpression = Expression.Evaluate(Source, #shared)
in EvaluatedExpression
```

Comment: So you think, i could do it by copying the queries in each files i want to work on? In that case is it possible to write a VBA code that will execute all the queries for each files at the same time?